# Page layout assignments in 2GP

Tags: managed-package, unlocked-package, 2gp, 2gp-ama

We are working on 2GP for one of our applications. We are facing one issue that page layout assignment is not happening after the installation of 2GP. Our package contains everything including the profile(admin) with layout assignments.
Did anyone face the issue?

Thanks,
Balaji M

Answer (score 1):

For Standard objects, page layout assignment doesn't happen automatically with package installation.  we have to assign manually after installation.